# How to find the parametric equation of the intersection of $z=x²+y²$ with $y=x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How to find such intersection? After that, how to find its parametric equation? I need it because I must solve the line integral:

$$\int_Y dx + ydy +dz$$

in the curve of the intersection of $z=x²+y²$ with $y=x$, $z\le 2$, from $(-1,-1,2)$ to $(1,1,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\bf{x}}=x{\bf{i}}+x{\bf{j}}+2x^2{\bf{k}}$$

[image]

Comment: It's my grief that I can't give $\gt+1$. By the way, The hat is looking nice.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $t=x$ as the parameter. This gives you parametric equations
$$
(x,y,z) = (t,t,2t^2) \quad (-1 \le t \le 1)
$$

The surface is a paraboloid, with its axis along the $z$-axis, and slicing it with the plane $y=x$ gives you a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note that you don't actually need the parametric equations, as the integral is equivalent to
$$
\int_Y \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_Y \nabla f \cdot d\vec{r} = f(1,1,2)-f(-1,-1,2),
$$

with $f(x,y,z)=x+\frac{y^2}{2}+z$.

You can check that both methods will give you an integral that equals 2.